# foreign key showing NOT

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables,
table 1) Doctor - with attribute of:

- id(primary key)
- fname
- lname
- phone
- beeper

table 2) Patient - with attribute of

- id(primary key)
- doctor$id(foreign key from doctor table id)
- fname
- lname
- street
- city
- state
- zip
- phone

And my question is how to "list out the id, number, first name, and last name of all doctors who do *not* have any patients assigned to him or her. Put the list in order of doctor's last name.

Comment: what is exact problem or error you are facing??

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with the `NOT IN` predicate:

```
SELECT 
  d.fname, 
  d.lname
FROM Doctor AS d
LEFT JOIN patient AS p ON d.id = p.doctor_id
WHERE p.docutor_id IS NULL
ORDER BY d.lname;
```

---

**Or:** The `NOT IN` predicate, but it is not safe with the `NULL` values coming from the `doctor_id` in `patient` table, thats why I added `NOT NULL` predicate to the `patient` table:

```
SELECT 
  d.fname, 
  d.lname
FROM Doctor AS d
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT doctor_id
                FROM patient
                WHERE docutor_id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY d.lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `not exists` :

```
 select id, fname, lname 
 from Doctor d 
 where not exists (select 1 from Patient where doctorId = d.id)
```